# Python yaml dump confuse

Tags: python, json, yaml

Let's say I have a json file like below, call it `src.json`.

```
{
    "main": {
        "contenttype": "Document"
    },
    "dublin": {
        "title": "ダウンロード",
        "description": "",
        "creators": [
            "池田大作"
         ],
        "created": "2012-04-23 10:09:34.642940"
    }
}
```

I wanna dump the `dublin` contents to `dst.yaml` using `yaml` in `python`.

Here is  my code:

```
import json
import yaml

with open('src.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

dump = {'title': data.get('dublin', {}).get('title', ''),
        'description': data.get('dublin', {}).get('description', ''),
        'creator': data.get('dublin', {}).get('creators',[''])[0],
        'created': data.get('dublin', {}).get('created', '')
       }
with open('dst.yaml', 'w') as stream:
    yaml.safe_dump(dump, stream, allow_unicode=True )
```

However, I am not satisfied with the result:

```
{created: '2010-03-26 09:26:44.002029', creator: 池田大作, description: '    ', title: ダウンロード}
```

The satisfied one should be :

```
created: 2010-03-26 09:26:44.002029
creator: 池田大作
description: ''
title: ダウンロード
```

Then, my questions are:

1. Why `'2010-03-26 09:26:44.002029'` has single quotes while `title` and `creator` not?
   How to remove single quotes around the date ?
2. Where is the line break? It should have with yaml dumping operation.

Any one help!

Answer (score 6):

1. Because it has a space in it.
2. Set `default_flow_style=False` in your call to `yaml.dump()`.

---

Also, you don't need to do all of that reconstruction; you could just dump the existing dublin dict directly:

```
import json
import yaml

with open('src.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

with open('dst.yaml', 'w') as stream:
    yaml.safe_dump(data.get('dublin', {}), stream, allow_unicode=True,
                   default_flow_style=False)
```